# Clean up a date output with windows CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to take a date output thats generated from LabTech that looks like "2014-08-31T23:59:59" and clean it up so it looks like 2014-08-31.  LabTech will run the cmd, so it does not need to be something entered in by a user. I just need help writing a hardcoded script that as soon as it is run in a CMD session it will output that date cleaned up.

I need this to be done with a CMD command (a batch script would work fine).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what exactly you are trying to tell us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable way:

```
@echo off
echo enter your date to clean:
set /p mydate=
set mydate=%mydate:~1,10%
echo.%mydate%
```

hardcoded way:

```
@echo off
set mydate="2014-08-31T23:59:59"
set mydate=%mydate:~1,10%
echo.%mydate%
```

String manipulation reference...
http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: You should really link to that other answer.

Comment: Thanks for this - but I don't need it to output the current date, I need it to take the outputted date of "2014-08-31T23:59:59" and turn it into 2014-08-31.  This output is going to be a variable, so it needs to work with any date outputted in that way.

Comment: added set /p for you so you can enter in any date/time as long as it's in that same format it should work fine

Comment: Man you are awesome - last tweak, the date has the quotation marks. Can you update this so it cleans it up while removing the quotations?

Comment: done. You just need to change ~1,10%.... 1= starting position 10 = amount of characters to grab after starting point. updated the script

Comment: thanks - would you update this one last time with a hard coded date in it? I can edit the file with the variables by modifying the .bat with a different program.

Comment: yeah done. please mark as answer and maybe update your question to state that you want that exact string, not the output of the command date. Kinda confusing. This will help others get answers :)

Comment: The hardcoded method is coming back with a strange output. Not the clean output of the date of the first method.  I'll update the question now

Comment: should be fine now. I fixed it shortly after I commented. Good luck bud.